# Codeception, execute arbitrary xpath query from a Cept file

Tags: codeception

From an acceptance Cept file, how can I execute an arbitrary xpath query ? (and get the result)

By example, the method 'see' does not help me because according the documentation :

```
Note that the search is done after stripping all HTML tags from the body,
```

"See" only search in stripped string. I'm looking for a generic method for execute all type of xpath query I want. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Methods you can using in Cept file directly usually return only text value of matching node or a value of specific attribute.
If that is enough for you, you can use [grabTextFrom](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#grabTextFrom), [grabAttributeFrom](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#grabAttributeFrom) or [grabMultiple](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#grabMultiple).

If you want to get more attributes or do something more complicated, you can use [_findElements](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#_findElements) in the helper method:

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

class Functional extends \Codeception\Module
{

    public function doSomethingWithElements()
    {
        $elements = $this->getModule('PhpBrowser')->_findElements('//body/h1');
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            //do whatever you want with it
        }
    }
}
```